# heroic login - heroku-cli: Installing core plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

## heroic login - heroku-cli: Installing core plugins

I have a simple app trying to deploy on heroic account.
This is killing me! I can't make it to work.
Every time I rung heroku login Im getting this error.
What I can do?

```
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 ▸    npm ERR! error in /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/package.json'
 ▸    npm ERR! extraneous: heroku-cli-util /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
 ▸    npm ERR! error in /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/package.json'
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error installing package. 
 ▸    npm WARN install:heroku-cli-util EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esparse'
 ▸    npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/package.json'
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No description
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No repository field.
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No README data
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No license field.
 ▸    npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
 ▸    npm ERR! argv "/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node-v5.7.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node-v5.7.1-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js" "install" "heroku-apps" "heroku-cli-addons" "heroku-fork" "heroku-git" "heroku-local" "heroku-orgs" "heroku-pipelines" "heroku-run" "heroku-spaces" "heroku-status"
 ▸    npm ERR! node v5.7.1
 ▸    npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10
 ▸    npm ERR! path /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esparse
 ▸    npm ERR! code EACCES
 ▸    npm ERR! errno -13
 ▸    npm ERR! syscall unlink
 ▸    
 ▸    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esparse'
 ▸    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
 ▸    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esparse']
 ▸    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
 ▸    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
 ▸    npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
 ▸    npm ERR!   path: '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esparse' }
 ▸    npm ERR! 
 ▸    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
 ▸    
 ▸    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 ▸    npm ERR!     /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/npm-debug.log
 ▸    
 ▸    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 ▸    npm ERR! error in /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/package.json'
 ▸    npm ERR! extraneous: heroku-cli-util /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
 ▸    npm ERR! error in /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/package.json'
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error installing package. 
 ▸    npm WARN install:heroku-cli-util EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esparse'
 ▸    npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/package.json'
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No description
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No repository field.
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No README data
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No license field.
 ▸    npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
 ▸    npm ERR! argv "/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node-v5.7.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node-v5.7.1-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js" "install" "heroku-apps" "heroku-cli-addons" "heroku-fork" "heroku-git" "heroku-local" "heroku-orgs" "heroku-pipelines" "heroku-run" "heroku-spaces" "heroku-status"
 ▸    npm ERR! node v5.7.1
 ▸    npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10
 ▸    npm ERR! path /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esvalidate
 ▸    npm ERR! code EACCES
 ▸    npm ERR! errno -13
 ▸    npm ERR! syscall unlink
 ▸    
 ▸    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esvalidate'
 ▸    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
 ▸    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esvalidate']
 ▸    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
 ▸    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
 ▸    npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
 ▸    npm ERR!   path: '/Users/deangergoric/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/cardinal/node_modules/.redeyed.MODULES/.bin/esvalidate' }
 ▸    npm ERR! 
 ▸    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
 ▸    
 ▸    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 ▸    npm ERR!     /Users/deangergoric/.heroku/npm-debug.log
 ▸    
 ▸    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
 !    error getting commands pid 28024 exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, when using Cloud9 for development. It seemed to have the Heroku CLI already installed, but still didn't work.

I went to https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ and followed the instructions for Linux to run

> wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

in the console. Once this had run I then tried `heroku login` again and it worked.

Hope this helps.